# How to authenticate current-user when they click "Launch App" from google-apps-marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

In the launch-url, I only get the domain-name, no way to get a "userId" to get the details of the current user that clicked "Launch app".

And google requires that there be no 'login' pages for domain-admin after they click 'launch app'.

How do I get the userId and what do I query to check the current-users domain + email-address ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using the email scope described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth) (in the authorization scopes section), you can call [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) and then you can receive the user's email.